# PouchDB. Is there a way to work just locally, without revision marker?

Tags: pouchdb

I need to use PouchDB in an Ionic App but since I don't need it synced I would like to be able to `put`/`update`/etc docs without the need to get and send the `_rev`.

Is there a way to do this? I always need to store the doc in a variable to get the `_rev`?

Comment: "I don't need it synced" - don't use PouchDB then. Take a look at something like Dexie or Lovefield

Comment: Sadly this was already implemented, I *have* to work with it.

Comment: Then you'll always need to use `_rev`. PouchDB's creators have themselves said that if you don't need syncing, other options would be better. But I understand your constraints.

Comment: Well, thank you! I will do a workaround to do this a little bit more "unsync" friendly.